# Is it possible to draw polylines in Timemap.js?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I just want to ask,is this possible to create polyline and draw moving car in timemap.js ? just like this 
   [moving car](http://jsfiddle.net/kSKGs/8/).

```
 var carPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        map: map,
        geodesic : true,
        strokeColor : '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity : 1.0,
        strokeWeight : 2,
        icons: [{
          icon: iconcar,
            scale: .1,   
          offset: '100%'
        }],
    });
    var carPath = new google.maps.MVCArray();
    for ( var i = 0; i < path_start.length; i++) {
        if(i === 0) {
            carPath.push(path_start[i]);
            carPolyline.setPath(carPath);
        } else {
            setTimeout((function(latLng) {
                return function() {

                    carPath.push(latLng);
                    map.setCenter(latLng);
                };
            })(path_start[i]), 100 * i);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to move that car every time I drag the timeline. Is this possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think it should be possible.  You'd have to split up a portion of the timeline into X partitions, where X is the number of latitude and longitude coordinate pairs.  Next, you would need a listener to detect when the user is moving the slider and figure out a way to associate the slider's new position with the corresponding coordinate pair.  Finally, you have to push (or pop) the relevant points onto (or off of) the car's path, then update the map.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Timemap so this is just a general idea of how to do it.  I'm sure you could find out how to do it from their documentation and sample apps.